# SQLAlchemy query for M2M table returns a list of primary keys instead of entire object

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have a M2M table `Employee` which has a M2O to User for employer and employee

```
class User(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, index=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    _employee_relation = relationship("User",
                             secondary=Employee,
                             foreign_keys=[Employee.c.employee_id, Employee.c.employer_id],
                             primaryjoin="User.id == employee.c.employee_id",
                             secondaryjoin="User.id == employee.c.employer_id",
                             backref="employees"
                            )


Employee = Table(
    "employee",
    BaseModel.metadata,
    Column("employer_id", ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("employee_id", ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True),
)
```

I'm trying to get all employees where the `employer_id` is 1, but I'm now just getting a list of primary keys (I guess) instead of the entire object.

```
user_employee, user_employer = aliased(User), aliased(User)
employees = await db.execute(select(Employee, User)
                                 .join(user_employee, user_employee.id == Employee.c.employee_id)
                                 .join(user_employer, user_employer.id == Employee.c.employer_id)
                                 .where(Employee.c.employer_id == 1)
                                 )
return employees.scalars().all()
```

The result of the query above is:

```
[
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1
]
```

Comment: This is what `scalars()` do - "Return a ScalarResult filtering object which will return single elements rather than Row objects." If you don't want that to happen, there is no need to call `scalars()`.

Comment: @MatsLindh That solved the problem, although I'm not sure why. I have another more simple query such as `user = select(User).where(User.email == email)` with `return user.scalars().first()` which returns the entire object and not just the first item. Nevertheless, thanks. You can post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm guessing it might be related to only returning a single entity in that case - in your other example you're selecting multiple entities (Employee, User).